# Clase madre de un outer join no visible (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Buenas,

tengo esta select:

```
select 
    count(ob.obj_id) as appeareances,
    cl.id as classs,
    cl.intl_id as class_intl,
    cl.name as class_name,
    cf.name as classif_name,
    cf.intl_id as classif_intl,
    cf.id as classif  
from 
    code_obj_class cl,
    code_obj_classif cf   
    left outer join obj_class2 ob on 
        ob.obj_class_id = cl.id and 
        ob.obj_Classif_id = cf.id and 
        ob.end_Date > to_date('21.06.2017','DD.MM.YYYY')  
group by 
    classs,
    class_intl,
    class_name,
    classif_name,
    classif_intl,
    classif  
order by appeareances asc;
```

no entiendo porqué no me reconoce "ob.obj_class_id = cl.id", concretamente CL.ID.
Este es el mensaje de error:

```
ORA-00904: "CL"."ID": identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error en la línea: 5, columna: 53
```

alguna idea?

edito:

```
select count(ob.obj_id) as appeareances,
    cl.id as classs,
    cl.intl_id as class_intl,
    cl.name as class_name,
    cf.name as
    classif_name,
    cf.intl_id as classif_intl,
    cf.id as classif  
from
    code_obj_class cl,
    code_obj_classif cf,
    obj_class2 ob 
where
    ob.obj_class_id = cl.id and ob.obj_Classif_id = cf.id and 
    ob.end_Date > to_date('21.06.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')  
group by 
    cl.id,
    cl.intl_id,
    cl.name,
    cf.name,
    cf.intl_id,
    cf.id   
order by appeareances asc;
```

la select pura sin join, solo con cruce de tablas, con los mismo campos, si se ejecuta

Comment: `ORA-00904` puede deberse a un error en el nombre de una columna. Verifica: **a)** que los nombres de columna no sean una palabra reservada, **b)** que comiencen por una letra **c)** sea menor o igual a treinta caracteres **d)** constan sólo de caracteres alfanuméricos y los caracteres especiales ($ _ #); otros caracteres necesitan comillas dobles alrededor de ellos. Y también, al nombrarlas escríbelas tal y como se llaman en la tabla, si todo en mayúsculas, todo en mayúscula, si PascalCase, PascalCase, etc.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano, gracias por tu ayuda

Esta consulta funciona sin problemas: select name, intl_id, id from code_obj_class; ergo, el nombre está bien

Comment: No **supongas** que es la columna `id` la que está mal escrita... revisa y compara uno por uno los nombres de columnas que intervienen en las tablas, o haz `select identificador.* , otroidentificador.* ...`
 para comprobar si es otra cosa lo que falla. En la doc ese número de error se refiere a un nombre incorrecto de columna o de tabla, de identificador en definitva.

Comment: También si en el script de creación de tablas usaste comillas para nombrar las columnas vas a tener problemas. Oracle recomienda no usar comillas para nombrar tus identificadores y ponerlos todos en mayúsculas.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, no son los nombres ya que si en lugar de la join uso un cruce de tablas tal cual no da problemas, añado en el cuerpo

Answer (score 0):

Ya está, al parecer el `JOIN` es solo con la última tabla del `FROM`. Se soluciona haciendo todo con `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT count(ob.obj_id) AS appeareances
    ,cl.id AS classs
    ,cl.intl_id AS class_intl
    ,cl.NAME AS class_name
    ,cf.NAME AS classif_name
    ,cf.intl_id AS classif_intl
    ,cf.id AS classif
FROM code_obj_class cl
JOIN code_obj_classif cf ON cl.obj_classif_id = cf.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN obj_class2 ob ON ob.obj_class_id = cl.id
    AND ob.obj_Classif_id = cf.id
    AND ob.end_Date > to_date('21.06.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
GROUP BY cl.id
    ,cl.intl_id
    ,cl.NAME
    ,cf.NAME
    ,cf.intl_id
    ,cf.id
ORDER BY appeareances ASC;
```